# Question about first necessity for vectoric subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

In some places I see the necessity is that the subspace won't be an empty group.
and sometimes I see like the equivalent to that is that the subspace will include the 0 vector.
but it might not need the 0 vector to not be an empty group for example :
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
as a Subspace of 
$$
\mathbb{R}^3
$$

Comment: No that is not a subspace. It is just a vector with two coordinates that are not specified. At the very least a subspace needs to be a _set of_ vectors.

Comment: Ye I mean't to show that it is a subgroup of (a,b,c) that is not empty but also doesn't include 0 (0,0,0). unlike (a,b,0) which is a linear subspace of the vector space (a,b,c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subspace $S$ of a group $G$ is itself a group, so if it's not empty, then $\exists x \in S$, so then (as $S$ is a group) $-x \in S$, and (again, $S$ is a group) $x + (-x) = 0 \in S$

Comment: Oh makes sense  thanks ! But overall I guess it's better to check for the 0 right away because it can disqualify immediately instead of checking for it not being empty and then checking for scalar multiplication.

Comment: No, wait. You are thinking of vector spaces. There is no scalar multiplication here. A group is closed under the operation of the group, and under inverse (and some more stuff)

Comment: To check that $S$ is subgroup of $G$, you must check that all elements have inverse in $S$ and that $S$ is closed under the operation.

Also, you must check that it's nonempty. So, if you think $S$ is not really a subgroup, a fast way to prove it may be to show that $0 \notin S$. But if it is a subgroup, you must prove all the things listed above.

Comment: Oh I'm talking about a subspace of a vector space, didn't think of other cases.

Comment: Oh well, the answer is the same, only that we are focusing on the addition operation of the vector space (and to check that $S$ is a subspace you have to check other/more things that what I said, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I figured it out, for it to be a subspace it needs to not be empty **and** include the 0 vector, but it is enough to say it needs to include the 0 vector because it means it's not empty, so you show both terms at the same time.

Comment: if it's not empty, then it includes the $0$ vector automatically because of [see my answer]. Of course, if it includes the $0$ vector it's not empty, so it's equivalent. (The equivalence would be: a group $G$ is nonempty iff it includes the $0$ vector)